# Fill two image overlay like seekbar on touch event of image-view

Tags: android, android-imageview, seekbar, gauge

There are two image black and blue while touching on blue image it should fill like progress, I achieved using multiple cuts images without using canvas but not get `smoothness` on touch, like [100 Pushups application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=alexcrusher.just6weeks.pushups&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImFsZXhjcnVzaGVyLmp1c3Q2d2Vla3MucHVzaHVwcyJd).

Actually I'm trying to achieve similar like 100 Pushups application as I mention above, I got one  [link](http://blog.publicobject.com/2010/04/shush-ringer-restorer-update.html) to but that's achieved using canvas and I want to achieve using Images, I Google but no luck, any link or tutorial similar to that application(100 push-ups)?

[image]

Comment: And what is your actual question..?

Comment: @Veger when i touch on image and scroll like seekbar and second image will display as touch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's something I came up with using clip path. I'm using following images (coder colours) out of which background is a solid one and foreground one contains only blue circle on transparent background. First background image is drawn onto screen, then clip path is set so that progress image, foreground one, is drawn properly on top of it.

Background image; https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvxxj.png
Foreground image; https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aTdG.png

And the code;

```
private class ProgressView extends View {

    private Bitmap bgBitmap;
    private Bitmap fgBitmap;
    private RectF fullRect = new RectF();
    private Path clipPath = new Path();

    public ProgressView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        bgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                   context.getResources(), R.drawable.bg);
        fgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                   context.getResources(), R.drawable.fg);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        fullRect.right = getWidth();
        fullRect.bottom = getHeight();

        c.drawBitmap(bgBitmap, null, fullRect, null);

        float angle = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 3600 / 10.0f;

        clipPath.reset();
        clipPath.setLastPoint(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
        clipPath.lineTo(getWidth() / 2, getHeight());
        clipPath.arcTo(fullRect, -90, angle);
        clipPath.lineTo(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
        c.clipPath(clipPath);

        c.drawBitmap(fgBitmap, null, fullRect, null);

        invalidate();
    }   
}
```

Should it not be too difficult to replace my temporary images with decent ones and update the angle in a more appropriate way.

Comment: Please don't use this code! Clipping is really slow and looks awful on Android. You are better to draw it correctly in the first place!

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins Agreed, it would be best not to use clipping but what do you mean with _looks awful_?

Comment: To Summerise: Clipping is slower than drawing, and does NOT support anti aliasing - Also clipping is not supported by harware render.
http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/ - Read the comments about clipping.

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins i read it.but we can also remove the hardware acceleration if we want the clip.

Comment: Use a `BitmapShader` and Draw the bitmaps directly at the correct arc, no clipping needed then and you draw it directly :)

Answer (score 1):

It will be a custom view, and it will be handling the `onTouchEvent()` method and will redraw when the user touches the view.

The `onDraw()` method will be checking something like:

```
if(mIsBeingTouched){
  //set colour to touched
}
doDraw(canvas);
///....
```

So when the user touches the view, i would increment a count and then increase the arc count.

```
final float arcDistance = mCurrentCount * 3.6; //Based on a max of 100
canvas.drawArc(mBoundsRectF, 0f, mCurrentCount, mPaint);
```

Then that would draw based on the count.

Comment: thanks ,,,,but i am not using with color.in my case there is two images.