# Android How to rotate needle when speed changes?

Tags: android, gauge

I have written an application where I have a `speedometer` with a `needle`, and I am trying to rotate the needle around its `center` with the speed changes.

I calculate the speed values of download speed from the internet from that that angle also measured,

My Question is how to Fix the Needle one end at the center of speedometer?

How to rotate the needle with change of the angle values?

I am expected like this

[image]

here the needle not fix center position How to fix needle center of image like first image
 center

[image]

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981845/androidrotate-image-in-imageview-by-an-angle) might help.

Comment: post your animation code. in that when you are creating rotate animation pivoteX and piviteY values mite be wrong.

Comment: i just created a background image for speedometer and set one image view needle on that image..how to set needle at center?

Comment: HEllo can u tell me how can i achieved this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040597/fill-two-image-overlay-like-seekbar-on-touch-event-of-image-view/14380664#14380664

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a custom GaugeView I wrote:
GaugeView.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

public class GaugeView extends LinearLayout{

private int gaugeDiameter;      //Gauge radius
private int gaugeBackground;    //Gauge background resource
private int needleBackground;   //Needle background resource
private int needleWidth;        //Needle width
private int needleHeight;       //Needle height
private int needleX;            //Needle X position
private int needleY;            //Needle Y position
private int needleDeltaX;       //Needle's X position from the centre of gauge
private int needleDeltaY;       //Needle's Y position from the centre of gauge
private int deflectTime;        //Animation time when needle deflects to a higher angle
private int releaseTime;        //Animation time when needle deflects to a lower angle
private int pivotX;             //Needles X Axis of rotation
private int pivotY;             //Needles Y Axis of rotation
private int deltaXAxis;         //Needles new X Axis of rotation
private int deltaYAxis;         //Needles new Y Axis of rotation
private float currentValue;     //Current needle value
private float minValue;         //Minimum needle value
private float maxValue;         //Maximum needle value
private float currentAngle;     //Current angular position of needle(Used in rotate animation)
private float previousAngle;    //To store last known angular position of needle(Used in rotate animation)
private float minAngle;         //Minimum angle of needle
private float maxAngle;         //Maximum angle of needle
private float currentDegrees;   //Current angular position of needle

private boolean animateDeflect; //Enable/Disable rotate animation

NeedleDeflectListener NDL;
public interface NeedleDeflectListener { 
    /**Called when needle value or angle is changed*/
    public void onDeflect(float angle,float value);

    }

/**Register a callback to be invoked when the needle value/angle is changed.*/
public void setOnNeedleDeflectListener(NeedleDeflectListener eventListener) {
    NDL=eventListener;
    }

private AbsoluteLayout guageBack;
private LinearLayout gaugeNeedle;

/**Custom view used for creating analog gauges like speedometer*/
public GaugeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    if(!isInEditMode()){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gauge_layout,this);
        initView(); 
    }

}


private void initView() // Initializes the view
 {
    this.gaugeBackground=R.drawable.gauge_gradient;
    this.needleBackground=R.drawable.needle_gradient;
    this.gaugeDiameter=0;
    this.needleWidth=0;
    this.needleHeight=0;
    this.needleX=0;
    this.needleY=0;
    this.needleDeltaX=0;
    this.needleDeltaY=0;
    this.currentValue=0;
    this.minValue=0;
    this.maxValue=100;
    this.currentAngle=0;
    this.minAngle=0;
    this.maxAngle=360;
    this.deflectTime=0;
    this.releaseTime=0;
    this.pivotX=0;
    this.pivotY=0;
    this.previousAngle=0;
    this.deltaXAxis=0;
    this.deltaYAxis=0;
    this.currentDegrees=0;
    this.animateDeflect=true;
    this.gaugeNeedle=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.gaugeNeedleLay);
    this.guageBack=(AbsoluteLayout) findViewById(R.id.gaugeFrame);
    this.guageBack.setBackgroundResource(gaugeBackground);
    this.gaugeNeedle.setBackgroundResource(needleBackground);
    this.gaugeNeedle.bringToFront();
 }


/**Sets a background resource for the gauge*/
public void setGaugeBackgroundResource(int resID)
 {
    gaugeBackground=resID;
    guageBack.setBackgroundResource(0);
    guageBack.setBackgroundResource(gaugeBackground);
    guageBack.refreshDrawableState();
 }


/**Sets the Diameter of the gauge*/
public void setDiameter(int diameter)
 {
     gaugeDiameter=diameter;
     guageBack.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(gaugeDiameter,gaugeDiameter));  
 }


/**Sets a background resource for the needle*/
public void setNeedleBackgroundResource(int resID)
{
    needleBackground=resID;
    gaugeNeedle.setBackgroundResource(needleBackground);
}


/**Creates a needle at the centre of the gauge.
<br> <b>deltaX</b>: Adjusts needle's X position from the centre of gauge
<br> <b>deltaY</b>: Adjusts needle's Y position from the centre of gauge*/
public void createNeedle(int width,int height,int deltaX,int deltaY)
{
    this.needleWidth=width;
    this.needleHeight=height;
    this.needleDeltaX=deltaX;
    this.needleDeltaY=deltaY;

    this.needleX=guageBack.getLeft()+(gaugeDiameter/2)+needleDeltaX-needleWidth/2;
    this.needleY=guageBack.getTop()+(gaugeDiameter/2)+needleDeltaY;

    this.pivotX=needleWidth/2;
    this.pivotY=Math.abs(needleDeltaY);

    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(this.needleWidth,this.needleHeight,this.needleX,this.needleY);
    gaugeNeedle.setLayoutParams(params);
}

/**Sets a reference background for the gauge*/
public void setReferenceBackground()
{
    guageBack.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.degrees);
}

/**Removes the reference background of the gauge*/
public void removeReferenceBackground()
{
    guageBack.setBackgroundResource(this.gaugeBackground);
}

/**Sets the current needle value*/
public void setCurrentValue(float value)
{

    if(value>maxValue)
        this.currentValue=maxValue;
    else if(value<minValue)
        this.currentValue=minValue;
    else
        this.currentValue=value;

    this.currentAngle=(((this.currentValue-this.minValue)*(this.maxAngle-this.minAngle))
                                            /(this.maxValue-this.minValue))+this.minAngle;
    setCurrentAngle(this.currentAngle);

}

/**Sets the needle value range*/
public void setValueRange(float min_Value,float max_Value)
{
    this.minValue=min_Value;
    this.maxValue=max_Value;

}

/**Sets the needle angle range (0-360)*/
public void setAngleRange(float min_Angle,float max_Angle)
{
    if(min_Angle<0)
        min_Angle=0;
    if(max_Angle>360)
        max_Angle=360;
    this.minAngle=min_Angle;
    this.maxAngle=max_Angle;
}

/**Sets the current needle angle*/
public void setCurrentAngle(float angle)
{
    if(angle>maxAngle)
        this.currentAngle=maxAngle;
    else if(angle<minAngle)
        this.currentAngle=minAngle;
    else
        this.currentAngle=angle;


    RotateAnimation needleDeflection=new RotateAnimation(this.previousAngle, this.currentAngle,this.pivotX,this.pivotY){
         protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,Transformation t) {
             currentDegrees=previousAngle+(currentAngle-previousAngle)*interpolatedTime;
             currentValue=(((currentDegrees-minAngle)*(maxValue-minValue))/(maxAngle-minAngle))+minValue;
             if(NDL!=null) 
                 NDL.onDeflect(currentDegrees,currentValue);
             super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
         }

    };

    needleDeflection.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {@Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {}@Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {}@Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {previousAngle=currentAngle;}});


    if(currentAngle>this.previousAngle)
        needleDeflection.setDuration(this.deflectTime); 
    else
        needleDeflection.setDuration(this.releaseTime);

    if(!animateDeflect)
        needleDeflection.setDuration(0);

    needleDeflection.setFillAfter(true);
    this.gaugeNeedle.startAnimation(needleDeflection);
    this.gaugeNeedle.refreshDrawableState();
}

/**Sets the needle's animation time
<br> <b>deflectTime</b>: Time taken by the needle to deflect to a higher value/angle
<br> <b>releaseTime</b>: Time taken by the needle to deflect to a lower value/angle*/
public void setAnimationTime(int deflectTime,int releaseTime)
{
    this.releaseTime=releaseTime;
    this.deflectTime=deflectTime;
}

/**Sets the axis of needle rotation with respect to the centre of gauge*/
public void setDeltaAxis(int deltaX,int deltaY)
{
    this.deltaXAxis=deltaX;
    this.deltaYAxis=deltaY;
    this.pivotX=(needleWidth/2)+deltaXAxis;
    this.pivotY=deltaYAxis;
}

/**Returns the current needle angle*/
public float getCurrentAngle()
{
    return this.currentDegrees;
}

/**Returns the Background resource ID of the gauge*/
public int getGaugeBackgroundResource()
{
    return this.gaugeBackground;
}

/**Returns the Diameter of the gauge*/
public int getDiameter()
{
    return this.gaugeDiameter;
}

/**Returns the Background resource ID of the needle*/
public int getNeedleBackgroundResource()
{
    return this.needleBackground;
}

/**Returns the current needle value*/
public float getCurrentValue()
{
    return this.currentValue;
}

/**Returns the needle width*/
public int getNeedleWidth()
{
    return this.needleWidth;
}

/**Returns the needle height*/
public int getNeedleHeight()
{
    return this.needleHeight;
}

/**Returns the X position of needle*/
public int getNeedlePositionX()
{
    return this.needleX;
}

/**Returns the Y position of needle*/
public int getNeedlePositionY()
{
    return this.needleY;
}

/**Returns the X axis of rotation of needle*/
public int getNeedleAxisX()
{
    return this.pivotX;
}

/**Returns the X axis of rotation of needle*/
public int getNeedleAxisY()
{
    return this.pivotY;
}

/**Returns the minimum needle value*/
public float getMinValue()
{
    return this.minValue;
}

/**Returns the maximum needle value*/
public float getMaxValue()
{
    return this.maxValue;
}

/**Returns the minimum needle angle*/
public float getMinAngle()
{
    return this.minAngle;
}

/**Returns the maximum needle angle*/
public float getMaxAngle()
{
    return this.maxAngle;
}

/**Returns the needle deflect time*/
public int getDeflectTime()
{
    return this.deflectTime;
}

/**Returns the needle release time*/
public int getReleaseTime()
{
    return this.releaseTime;
}

/**Enable/disable needle animation*/
public void setNeedleAnimation(boolean EnableAnimation)
{
    this.animateDeflect=EnableAnimation;

}

/**Returns needle animation state*/
public boolean getNeedletAnimation()
{
    return this.animateDeflect;

}

}
```

And the `gauge_layout.xml` layout xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<AbsoluteLayout
    android:id="@+id/gaugeFrame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scaleType="fitXY" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gaugeNeedleLay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" >
    </LinearLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout></LinearLayout>
```

Implementation example:

```
final GaugeView gv=(GaugeView)findViewById(R.id.gaugeView1);
gv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gaugeback_image);
gv.setNeedleBackgroundResource(R.drawable.needle_image);
gv.setDiameter(460);
gv.createNeedle(50,230,0,-20);
gv.setAngleRange(45,315);
```

**UPDATE:**

`AbsoluteLayout` is deprecated. You can replace it with `RelativeLayout` and some code changes.

Comment: from this i am getting forceclose. in this drawble what is the purpose of gauge_background, needle_background and degrees could u explain?

Comment: `gaugeBackground` is the `drawable` which contains the speedometer values and skin. `needle_background` is the `drawable` which contains the image of the needle. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: `E/AndroidRuntime(622): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.gaugemeter/com.gaugemeter.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.gaugemeter.MainActivity; no empty constructor`  Run this code facing this error....

Comment: `com.gaugemeter.MainActivity` is that your launcher activivty?

Comment: Once see error log here  `http://pastebin.com/2Sq1svnD` faceing this issues provide any zip and extra class ...

Comment: how can i achieved this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040597/fill-two-image-overlay-like-seekbar-on-touch-event-of-image-view/14380664#14380664

Comment: dear @rIHaNJiTHiN, the above demo project URL is not working. can you please provide me a working URL ?

Comment: @ArunKumarMunusamy: Sorry, I don't have that project with me anymore. But, all the code used in that project is in the answer itself.

Comment: what is gv.setRadius(460); I do not see setRadius in the code

Comment: @JourneyWithAndroid it was supposed to be `setDiameter`. Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer.

Comment: this solution does not work of course for different screen sizes. Also , I assume that it works for the resources (needle and background) that used by @JiTHiN

Comment: This works for multiple screens, and you can adjust the position of needle.

Answer (score 5):

There are a bunch of ways to do this. Some thread that might help you:

[Android: Rotate image in imageview by an angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981845/androidrotate-image-in-imageview-by-an-angle)

[Android Speedometer (Needle Gauge)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450374/android-speedometer-needle-gauge)

[Android Gauge Animation Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156674/android-gauge-animation-question)

Here' a good tutorial I found that makes a vintage thermometer using a similar kind of animation:

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/